# Desabilitar o refresh automático de uma Grid

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, telerik

Olá, estou a muito tempo tentando desabilitar o refresh um `AjaxUpdatedControl` de uma `RadGrid` que ocorre quando eu clico em um botão desta Grid.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3):

Resolvido: Somente retirei a tag `<AjaxUpdatedControl>`.

Comment: Não é necessário escrever uma resposta apenas pra dizer "obrigado". A melhor maneira de agradecer é **[aceitando](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** a resposta que te ajudou. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/78840)

Comment: Olá @Diego, sim realmente é verdade, entretanto eu não consigo aceitar a minha própria resposta em menos de 2 dias.